# Sending microphone audio from client Flutter to server NodeJS

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io, audio-streaming

First, english is not my first language so I will try my best to explain right.
Im developing an app that connects to a server in nodejs and I want to record audio with microphone and send it to my server while is recording. Im currently using socket.io for both the client side and the server side. To record the audio using the microphone Im using audiorecord library because is the only library I found that works on the last version of flutter.

[Code of my flutter app where i try to send the microphone audio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2CKH.png)

Ive tried the code in the picture. I expect to receive in my server the recording audio in real time.